# Creating an array of button sprites with andengine NullpointerException

Tags: android, andengine

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out all day.  I had enough trouble getting the database to work (which it does now).  The problem I'm having is that I get a null pointer exception.  here is the important part of the file (its way too big to post the whole thing.

```
        db = new MyDatabase(activity);

    attackCursor = db.getPlayerAttackWeapons();
    attackButtons = new ButtonSprite[attackCursor.getColumnCount()];
    if (attackCursor != null) {


      attackCursor.moveToFirst();
      while (attackCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {         
        attackButtons[attackButtonsCounter] =  
                new ButtonSprite(0, 0, PlayerMenu.getPlayerMenuAttackTR(),
                engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    beep.play();
                    attackType = attackCursor.getInt(0);
                    this.setVisible(false);
                    selectTargetMessage.setVisible(true);
                    gameScene.unregisterTouchArea(this);
                    playerMenu.setVisible(false);
                    this.setParent(playerMenuAttack);

                }

                return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                        pTouchAreaLocalY);

            }
        };
        attackButtons[attackButtonsCounter].setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        attackButtons[attackButtonsCounter].setPosition(0,attackButtonsYpos - 0-attackButtons[attackButtonsCounter].getHeight());

        attackButtonsYpos = attackButtonsYpos - 90;

        attackButtonsCounter++;
        attackCursor.moveToNext();
      }

    }
```

Now, there isn't any errors coming up with this part of the code, however this should yield visible buttons on screen.  it does not.  Furthermore  the nullpointerexception is coming up in this portion of the code:

```
playerMenuAttack = new Sprite(0, 0, PlayerMenu.getPlayerMenuAttackTR(),
            engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                beep.play();
                int i = 0;
                while (i <= attackButtons.length)
                 {
                    //getButtonTogglers(attackButtons[i]);
                    attackButtons[i].setVisible(true);
                    i++;
                }

            }

            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);

        }
    };
    playerMenuAttack.setPosition(0,0);
```

I'm getting the nullpointer exception when I click on the playerMenuAttack sprite.  Its pointing to the line containing attackButtons[i].setVisible(true);  I'm at a total loss....

Comment: Small thing I noticed:  "while (i <= attackButtons.length)" should be "while (i < attackButtons.length)".  Also, in that same while loop, log every time attackButtons[i] == null.  How many cases do you get?

Comment: Do you add these buttons to the view?   Say your view is named myView, then myView.addView(attackButtons[i]);

Comment: I had to delete my previous comment, it made no sense.  I have one instance of the log error.

Comment: Which instance is it?

Comment: using andengine, so in order to make the sprites viewable on screen the command: this.attachParent(playerMenuAttack);  However i just tried it the other way around: playerMenuAttack.attachChild(this);  and it didn't make a difference at all.

Comment: hm... the instance is 2... but I've only got 2 records total being 0 and 1.  I think you might have found my problem.  Stay Tuned.

Comment: Also, make sure your buttons have onClickListeners

Comment: So I just changed the line:  while (i < attackButtons.length) to  while (i < 2) since I know for now how many records are in the database.  Now I don't have any nullpointer exceptions but my generated sprites are still nowhere to be seen on scree.

Comment: You mean (i<2) because they only occupy position 0 and 1?

Comment: Yeah.  I'll register the buttons to be listeners once I've established that they can be viewed on screen.

Comment: Yeah.. I mean't less than two.  got in a rush in the comment

Comment: Do you have a main scene?  Like mainScene.attachChild(playerMenuAttack) and mainScene.attachChild(attackButtons[attackButtonsCounter])?

Comment: figured out where my nullpointerexception came from.  When I was initializing my attackButtons[] array I was using cursor.getColumnCount instead of cursor.getCount... Such a dumb mistake.  However, as I figured there is another mistake since I cannot see the two buttons that should be visible.

Comment: Can you edit in your question your newest code?